# Unable to save a file due to file permissions

Tags: php, file, file-io, permissions, chmod

I'm trying to upload and save an image file. This has worked fine in the past, but is now returning an error.

**Warning**:  move_uploaded_file(//home/bitnami/htdocs/lookgram/photos/1/22.jpeg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in **/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lookgram/build/classes/Photo.php** on line **138**

**Warning**:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpAyWyw4' to '//home/bitnami/htdocs/lookgram/photos/1/22.jpeg' in **/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/lookgram/build/classes/Photo.php** on line **138**

This looks like a file permssion error, so here is the permissions on the folder:

`drwxrwxr-x  6 bitnami bitnami    4096 Mar 15 01:02 photos`

Any ideas?

Comment: When you are looking to a rights values, you have `drwxrwxr-x`. So for you (bitnami) `rwx`, for the group `rwx` but for other, just `r-x`. So user that are not in the group can just read and execute, not writting anything. I assume that the user used by your PHP is not in the group.

Comment: If the PHP is just being executed by my webserver, who is the 'user'?

Comment: Try this: `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>` in your script an tell us who it is

Comment: It returns "daemon". What user will daemons fall into?

Comment: Check what is the group of bitnami (you) with `groups bitnami`. Then you can add your "daemons" user to your group `useradd -G group_name daemons`. Then you should be able to make your move_file. You can also decide to change the group of the directory with `chgrp`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `photos/1/` is only writable by `root` user. For upload to work we need to make the owner of that folder same as httpd process owner OR make them globally writable (bad practice).

1. Check apache process owner: `$ps aux | grep httpd`. The first column will be the owner typically it will be `nobody`
2. Change the owner of `photos/1/` to be become `nobody` or whatever the owner you found in step 1.

   `$sudo chown nobody /home/bitnami/htdocs/lookgram/photos/1/`
3. Chmod `photo/1/` now to be writable by the owner, if needed [Seems you already have this in place].

   `$ sudo chmod -R 0755 /home/bitnami/htdocs/lookgram/photos/1/`
4. For more details why this behavior happen, check the manual http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir , note that it also talking about open_basedir directive.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you Sumit. 

My use is 'daemon'. So I will make these changes for that user.